# Phonegap + Jquery Mobile run time from clicking icon to main index.html

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using Phonegap + Jquery Mobile, when I click the icon on the phone, it takes a long time to show the index.html, now I added a splash screen, it shows the splash screen then a black screen before it loads the index.html. the index.html is just very small with cordova.js, and the jquery mobile js. 
how do I correct this?

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.phonegap.test222"
    version   = "1.0.21">
<name>Test App</name>
<description>
Beta Saystyle
</description>
<author href="http://example.com" email="example@example.com">
Lester Jan Pearson
</author>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="300" />
<icon src="images/4.png" />
<gap:splash src="images/mohawk.png" />
</widget>
```

Comment: for me also same problem. it's taking time to load index.html page. it is taking nearly 3-5 seconds to load in phone when app runs. if you find the solution please post it...

Comment: do you use same config.xml? more or less I mean

Comment: what is the use of config.xml for android? if you are running phonegap through blackberry webworks means you need to use config.xm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Phonegap 1.7 or better take a look at the changes I did the to the splash screen.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/04/phonegap-android-splashscreen-just-got.html

Now your page loads in the background while the splash screen is being shown. As well you can call a method to hide the splash screen once you get to deviceready so it isn't shown any longer that it needs to be.

Comment: I'm using cordova-1.7.0.js is that desame? any idea if the Dreamweaver cs6 has the latest phonegap?

Comment: Is phonegap slower than other builders? what other builders are there.

Comment: No idea on Dreamweaver, I don't work for Adobe. What do you mean builders?

Comment: Do you think phonegap is faster than titanium?

Comment: I honestly can't answer that as I have not used Titanium.

Comment: thats cool, anyways thanks for the info, really helpful. I will let you know once I apply this.